# OpenCV video processing tutorial issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, opencv, computer-vision

I followed the [iOS video processing tutorial on the OpenCV site](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html) and managed to compile and install it on the device. However when I click on the "Start" button, nothing visible happens. Apparently neither my `- (void)processImage:(Mat&)image` callback is never called. Could you give me some hints what could be the problem?

Some things I checked:

- `actionStart` is called, and both log lines prints YES
- the `self` object is valid when assigned to `self.videoCamera.delegate`
- `imageView` is valid and visible on the screen
- `videoCamera` is initialized when its `start` method is called

I use a iPhone 3GS for testing.

Here is the full source of my ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CvVideoCameraDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView* imageView;
    IBOutlet UIButton* button;

    CvVideoCamera* videoCamera;
}

- (IBAction)actionStart:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, strong) CvVideoCamera* videoCamera;

@end
```

and ViewController.mm:

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize videoCamera;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:imageView];
    self.videoCamera.delegate = self;

    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionFront;
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288;
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
    self.videoCamera.defaultFPS = 30;
    self.videoCamera.grayscaleMode = NO;

}

#pragma mark - UI Actions

- (IBAction)actionStart:(id)sender;
{
    [self.videoCamera start];
    NSLog(@"video camera running: %d", [self.videoCamera running]);
    NSLog(@"capture session loaded: %d", [self.videoCamera captureSessionLoaded]);
}

#pragma mark - Protocol CvVideoCameraDelegate

- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)image
{
    // Do some OpenCV stuff with the image
    cv::Mat image_copy;
    cvtColor(image, image_copy, CV_BGRA2BGR);

    // invert image
    bitwise_not(image_copy, image_copy);
    cvtColor(image_copy, image, CV_BGR2BGRA);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tested on an iPhone 4 and it works well. Maybe the iPhone 3GS doesn't have a front facing camera? Then you have to change this line: `self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionFront` to `self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack`

Comment: You are absolutely right, this was the problem. Damn, I spent 1 day with this :)