# Duplicate interface definition for class 'ViewController'

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, opencv

Complete newcomer to iOS development, and following this [tutorial, OpenCV iOS](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/dc8/tutorial_video_processing.html)... but get the aforementioned error when I add

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView* imageView;
    IBOutlet UIButton* button;
}
```

I understand this is happening because the namespace ViewController has already been used, and, that I can avoid it by extending the declared class by adding () to make it a private class? This doesn't work. Any tips?

-- also any links to a programmatic intro to xcode? Cheers!!

Comment: Also, what does the ": UIViewController" mean??

Comment: ViewController is Class name and UIViewController is its Parent Class. Inheritance.

Comment: `Duplicate` : You cannot use same Class Name "ViewController" twice.

Comment: Could you please show the complete code? Where have you declared ViewController by adding(). Does your project contains @interface ViewController more than once?

Comment: Thanks all for the tips, I'm using source, copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274326/opencv-video-processing-tutorial-issue, and now have errors of a different type :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting confused over declarations in header/main files; and by declaring the ViewController a second time in the main file caused the above error.

Source in header:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController 
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView* imageview;
    IBOutlet UIButton* button;
    CvVideoCamera* videoCamera;
}
```

in main:

```
@interface ViewController()
@end
```

Useful answer regarding extending VC instead of clashing namespaces [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32491138/5827385), and full source code or OpenCV video processing in iOS copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274326/opencv-video-processing-tutorial-issue).